# Collision detection for enemy coming in contact with player

Tags: python, pygame

I was confused as to why my player could detect collision with the enemy but it couldn't be the other way round. The enemy seems to be touching him but when I print the collision it still gives me false. However if I write my collision statement in my player class which is similar to my enemy class, it works. The collision statement for the enemy is at the bottom.

Thanks

```
def CollisionDetect(x1,y1,w1,h1,x2,y2,w2,h2):

    if x2+w2>=x1>=x2 and y2+h2>=y1>=y2:
        return True
    elif x2+w2>=x1+w1>=x2 and y2+h2>=y1+h1>=y2:
        return True
    elif x2+w2>=x1>=x2 and y2+h2>=y1>=y2:
        return True
    elif x2+w2>=x1+w1>=x2 and y2+h2>=y1+h1>=y2: 
        return True
    else:
        return False


class Enemy:
    def __init__(self,x,y):    
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.width=55
        self.height = 51
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height)
        self.speed=1
        self.s0 = pygame.image.load("s0.png")
        self.s1 = pygame.image.load("s1.png")
        self.s2 = pygame.image.load("s2.png")
        self.s3 = pygame.image.load("s3.png")
        self.attack = pygame.image.load("attack.png")
        self.rotateds0 = pygame.transform.flip(self.s0 ,True, False)
        self.rotateds1 = pygame.transform.flip(self.s1 ,True, False)
        self.rotateds2 = pygame.transform.flip(self.s2 ,True, False)
        self.rotateds3 = pygame.transform.flip(self.s3 ,True, False)
        self.rotate = False   
        collision2 = False
        self.TimeTarget=10
        self.TimeNum=0
        self.currentImage=0        

    def move(self,player):
        if player.x > 100:
            if self.x > player.x:
                self.x -= self.speed
                if self.currentImage > 3:
                    self.currentImage = 0                    
            elif self.x < player.x:
                self.x += self.speed
                if self.currentImage < 4:    
                    self.currentImage = 4

            if self.x < player.x:
                if self.x > player.x:
                    if self.currentImage > 3:
                        self.currentImage = 0                    


    def update(self,CollisionDetect,player):        
        self.TimeNum+=1
        if self.TimeNum == self.TimeTarget:                
            if self.currentImage ==0:
                self.currentImage=1   
            elif self.currentImage ==1:
                self.currentImage=2    
            elif self.currentImage == 2:
                self.currentImage=3    
            elif self.currentImage ==3:
                self.currentImage =0                
            elif self.currentImage ==4:
                self.currentImage=5    
            elif self.currentImage ==5:
                self.currentImage=6    
            elif self.currentImage == 6:
                self.currentImage=7    
            elif self.currentImage ==7:
                self.currentImage = 4    

            self.TimeNum=0

        if self.currentImage==0:    
            screen.blit(self.s0, (self.x,self.y))    
        elif self.currentImage==1:
            screen.blit(self.s1, (self.x,self.y))                
        elif self.currentImage==2:
            screen.blit(self.s2, (self.x,self.y))    
        elif self.currentImage ==3:
            screen.blit(self.s3, (self.x,self.y))            

        elif self.currentImage==4:
            screen.blit(self.rotateds0, (self.x,self.y))    
        elif self.currentImage==5:
            screen.blit(self.rotateds1, (self.x,self.y))                
        elif self.currentImage==6:
            screen.blit(self.rotateds2, (self.x,self.y))    
        elif self.currentImage ==7:
            screen.blit(self.rotateds3, (self.x,self.y))

        collision2 = CollisionDetect(self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height,player.x,player.y,player.width,player.height)
```

Comment: CollisionDetect is not correct : statement 1 and 3 are equal, and 2 and 4 also equal. It's not the core problem, but maybe. If you want, I can rewrite it for you.

Comment: I would be interested to see your version of it! and yeah... i just realised that.. feel reaaally  stupid

Answer (score 0):

Maybe can help:

```
def CollisionDetect(x1,y1,w1,h1,x2,y2,w2,h2):
     return abs(x1+w1/2-x2+w2/2)<((w1+w2)/2) and abs(y1+h1/2-y2+h2/2)<((h1+h2)/2)
```

It's a easier version of your, and I will try to explain more about it:

Maybe easier to understand with 1 dimensions :

abs(x1+w1/2-x2+w2/2) mean I'm searching for distance between middle of two segment.

-------[a--b--c]---------[d-e-f]-------

- a : x1
- b : x1+w1/2
- c : x1+w1
- d : x2
- e : x2+w2/2
- f : x2+w2

What I want is the distance from two middle point are not more important than the width from middle to border of each point.

So, abs(b - e) < ([b-c]+[d-e]) => abs(b - e) < (w1/2+w2/2) => abs((x1+w1/2)-(x2+w2/2)) < (w1/2+w2/2)

Comment: a little explanation, I hope it's help